# Chackdate confirmation

Tags: php, datetime, explode

I'm not getting true result. I've set all date timezones on my computer also php ini file.

```
<?php   
$orig_date="15/10/2016";
$date=explode("/","$orig_date");
$month=$date[0];
$day=$date[1];
$year=$date[2];
$result=checkdate($month,$day,$year);
if($result==true){
echo 'Date is valid';
}else{
echo 'Date is not valid';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$month`, `$day` variable assignments are incorrect. The date string you provided is in `d/m/Y` format, but after [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) you are using **0th** index as month, which should have been day (as **15** cannot be month number), so change to

```
...
$date=explode("/",$orig_date);
$month=$date[1]; //month can be only 1 & 12 inclusive
$day=$date[0];
$year=$date[2];
$result=checkdate($month,$day,$year);
...
```

Comment: I've tried that and it true in that case, but when I changed 15 to another number in $orig_date it's still true :)

Comment: @NikolaPetrović what number did you change it to, as the first part (15) in your $orig_date is Day number , the day number is within the allowed number of days for the given month. Leap years are taken into consideration. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php for more information.

Comment: I tried to change it to 16 and few more numbers from 01 to 31 and it stays true. I'm freakin' out slowly